# Querying DynamoDB index with low distribution

Tags: optimization, amazon-dynamodb

Just wanting to see if this is the best way of solving this problem.

**Scenario**

We are building an online sports manager game. In our game there are teams, and the teams will play each other in what we call "fixtures".

At the start of each season, the fixtures for the season are created and entered into a table, e.g. A fixture item might specify team 1 vs team 2, December 1st 7pm.

Gameplay for each fixture is created at the fixture start time to take into account changes the team owners may have made up until that point.

We have a scheduler which needs to check the table for fixtures which: 1) have not run, and 2) whose start date is `<=` now. We include "less than" so that if there are system issues or downtime, we can catch up on any matches which may still be waiting to run.

**Problem**

How do we search a large dynamodb table for fixtures which have not run yet, and whose start date is now or earlier.

**Current Solution**

The current plan is to create a boolean field called `HasNotRun` initially set to `true`, along with the `Date` field. We then create a sparse global secondary index using the `HasNotRun` field as the partition key to get all fixtures not run yet, and use `Date` as a sorted range key, and filter on it. Once the match is run, the `HasNotRun` field is removed from the item, and thus the item is removed from the sparse index.

However, given that the `HasNotRun` field will always be a single value of `true`, all items in this index will always be in a single partition which doesn't seem like the best way to use DynamoDB.

**A better way?**

If there is a better way to solve this problem, we'd love to hear it. We know it's out there!

Answer (score 0):

Your solutions is actually quite good. Having a single key is not actually as bad as it sounds, because all the throughput will go to that single key. Problems would arise if you had more than one key with non-uniform query distribution. With only one key you are not going to have that problem. However, it can potentially cause different type of issue if you expect very high throughput: if total number of items in this GSI is below 10GB then you will be limited by single partition throughput limits(3000RCU and 1000WCU I think). If it gets above 10GB then second partition will be created and max throughput will be limited to 6000/2000 respectively, and so on.

One way you could improve your solution is to use shards instead of boolean value. Instead of assigning value of "true", assign a random number from 1 to N (N depends on your scaling plans, and can also be dynamically adjusted). You query will now need to do N queries for each key (you can do it in parallel) and then merge results. This solution does not suffer from the problem mentioned in first paragraph.